# Printing wide SVG image with embedded PNG/JPG

Tags: svg, printing, inkscape

I'm struggling to find a way of printing a wide SVG image. This is a common problem so let me explain my specific problem.

The image is wide and so I need to tile it (poster fashion) across about 5 or 6 A4 sheets (actual count not important). My first problem is that the default Print dialog in my Firefox or Chrome browsers, under Windows, do not allow me to scale the image height to fit the page height while also spreading the image width across multiple pages.

Someone else suggested using Inkscape to convert to PDF format as the Print dialog in Acrobat reader has better support for tiling. Well, it does, but Inkscape does not deal with embedded images (e.g. PNG or JPG). Worse still, it generates huge square error markers saying "Linked image not found" all over. These are also preserved in the generated PDF which makes it useless.

There are lots of online tools that claim they can convert SVG to PDF. I tried a handful and none coped with embedded images. They were simply discarded.

So, I'm basically looking for any route to print a wide SVG image onto a horizontal series of pages, and that preserves any embedded PNG/JPG images.

[Edit]
Some of the online results:
zamzar -- images discarded
cloudconvert -- simply used inkscape
convertio -- best of the bunch, but opacity ignored on images
online-convert.com -- images discarded
pdfresizer -- simply used inkscape
freefileconvert --  simply used inkscape
onlineconvertfree -- failed with basic SVG
pdfaid -- massively failed with basic SVG

[Edit 2]
Here are a few lines of code that show one of the embedded internet-based PNG references. This one is designed to provide a faint background image underneath the subsequent SVG shapes. Hence the opacity of 12%.

```
<defs>
    <pattern id="img2" width="50%" height="100%" >
        <image xlink:href="https://clipartart.com/images/tree-branch-clipart-png-4.png" x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="100%" />
    </pattern>
</defs>


<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#img2)" fill-opacity="0.12" />
```

Comment: When Inkscape says 'Linked image not found', it could be just that - are you sure they are embedded? Can you share the file, or part of it?

Additionally, there is a bug in a library that Inkscape uses, that has the effect that specific jpg images cannot be read (https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/issues/964).
(btw. interesting to know who is using Inkscape-as-a-service!). I didn't know it could also affect png images, but who knows...

Comment: The images are fine, and can be referenced by other software such as browsers. I found some "small print" on the Inkscape site that said internet-based images are not supported for"security reasons". That sounds a little like the Wordpress scaremongering around SVG. If it's running on my machine, and I created the references, then it's my responsibility. It's really annoying, both in practice and in principle.

Comment: Yep, that is indeed intentional. Not everyone creates those files themselves.

Comment: But then it should be something you can turn off, Moni. I see no justification for completely ruining the view, and persisting it in the saved PDF, as opposed to just discarding those images.

Comment: For bug reports and feature requests, please use https://inkscape.org/report , @ACProctor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had time to experiment with this further (and so wasting printer paper by the shed-load).

1) Inkscape deliberately does not support Internet image references (e.g. http) for "security reasons". As mentioned, it puts a horrible error marker in the view of the loaded SVG and I have found no way to edit it out. Hence, it gets saved in any PDF version.

2) If I download local copies of the images and change their http:// references to equivalent file:/// (yes, 3 slashes) then they are accepted.

3) This allows a PDF copy to be saved, but if any of the images had an opacity (e.g. a background image) then that gets lost and it is full opacity in the PDF. This may be a conversion issue or a PDF limitation -- I do not know.

4) Since I then have local copies of the images, they can be changed to implement any faintness required "at source".

5) The Acrobat Print dialog has a Poster option for tiling the pages of a wide image. Ensuring no 'cut marks' or 'labels' are added, you can set a 'Tile scale' that keeps the height within one page, and it will spread it over as many pages as necessary for the width. On the basis of the scaling, it selects landscape/portrait itself and ignores any selection of your own.

So, problems? Yes, the Acrobat 'Overlap' setting is a mystery, leaving a thin white margin on either one or both of adjoining sheets in the output. I have not been able to correlate the width of this margin, or the appearance on one or both sheets, with this setting.

Via the Preferences button, I can get to the normal printer preferences dialog, where I can request 'Borderless printing'. Rather than fixing the issue, this just makes the correlations even more mysterious.

Comment: For 3) the pdf version, operating system and Inkscape version (as in Help > About) as well as info about filters on the objects and rasterization settings on pdf export could be relevant.